# Referencing a sequence template as a scheduled task

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have been trying out scheduled tasks and they work when i reference a sequence but when i use a sequence template, i get errors

This is my scheduled task code

```
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="CheckGrandOak" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <trigger interval="5"/>
    <property name="sequenceName" value="ScheduledTask" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="format" value="text/xml" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="message" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks">
        <message xmlns="">Welcome to the new world</message>
    </property>
    <property name="injectTo" value="template" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
</task>
```

this is my API code

```
<api context="/tasks" name="ScheduledTasks" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <log>
                <property name="message" value="This is the API"/>
            </log>
            <call-template target="ScheduledTask"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

My template sequence is called 'ScheduledTask.xml'

Goal:
I want to reference a sequence from a template using a scheduled task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inject a message into a `Sequence Template` from a scheduled task. It seems the code only supports the following types. See the code [here](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/startup/tasks/MessageInjector.java#L96).

```
proxy
sequence
```

As a workaround wrap the `Sequence Template` with another `Sequence` or a `Proxy Service`.

---

**Update**

I checked the code a little more and it seems there is another task implementation that does this job. Although you can't call a `Sequence Template` with the `org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector` impl, you can use `org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.TemplateMessageExecutor`. Take a look at the following example configs.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.TemplateMessageExecutor" group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="TestTask" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <trigger count="10" interval="5"/>
    <property name="templateKey" value="ScheduledTask" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="templateParams" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks">
        <request xmlns=""/>
    </property>
</task>
```